# Adding reset.css into Rails project

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have tried to insert a reset.css inside the stylesheets folder. The purpose is to overwrite the browser's default styling. After I created the reset.css file, I linked this file inside application.html.erb:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/stylesheets/reset.css">
```

However, the reset.css file seems to overwrite other stylesheets, for example the Bootstrap link. What is the correct way of inserting/linking reset.css file in Rails?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of rails you are using?

Comment: Hi @SyedAsimHashmi, I am using Rails 6.0.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried organizing css in the `application.css` file as below:

```
 /*
     *= require reset
     *= require layout
     *= require header
     *= require footer
    */
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Hi @nileshkumar, I have tried this and then I got error message below: `Sprockets::FileNotFound in Pages#welcome
Showing /Users/huangzheng/RubymineProjects/portfolio_ruby_on_rails/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #11 raised:

couldn't find file 'reset' with type 'text/css' ` I think the 'require reset' corresponds to a specific gem that I have to install instead of  linking to a stylesheet that I created inside the stylesheet folder. I am new to Rails though, not sure about this.